# Anonymous structs in C

Tags: c, visual-studio, debugging

We are working with Visual Studio 2019 on Windows 10 Pro (x64) in plain old, native C.  We were working on a little throw-away program to test a communication link yesterday and discovered that the code below compiles and runs, but confuses the VS2019 debugger:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct
{
   char *label;
   int   value;
} one[2] =
{
   { "one", 1 },
   { "two", 2 },
};

struct
{
   int   prox;
   DWORD fuse;
   float debug;
} two[6];

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
   DebugBreak();
   return 0;
}
```

When at the breakpoint (hard-coded in the example we gave Microsoft), the debugger will show the wrong member variable names and values for one of the two anonymous structs in tooltips that show the variable's value and the watch window with the variables specified.

My question is:  Other than it being a bad coding practice, is there any reason why this code is wrong (strictly in a C compiler sense)?

I guess I'm interested in finding the standard reference to give Microsoft if they try to tell me that this bug is my fault (though I believe that either their compiler or debugger must be broken, since the code should either not compile/link or should debug correctly, right?)

Comment: I don't even see where it is a "bad practice". The only bad practice is to use MSVC and hope that it will comply with some C standards...

Comment: This is a little vague.  Can you be more specific about the errors you are having?

Comment: However, I can reproduce any problems with this code in VS2017. Tooltips show correct values. Watch windows show correct values. Everything looks fine. What version are you using?

Comment: @AnT This is C, and `char*` is bad practice, but not wrong.

Comment: Oh, my mistake. I missed the [C] tag. However, the debugger shows everything correctly in C version as well. Also, note that if you point the mouse pointer at one of the brackets in the `[2]` part, the tooltips will display the value of `one[2]` expression, which is garbage for obvious reasons.  If you point the mouse at `one`, they will correctly show the values in the array. The same behavior applies to the second array as well.

Comment: No, flagging it as "not reproducible".

Comment: As stated on the FIRST LINE of my post, I'm using VS2019.  Microsoft has placed my report in "Triaged" and I included a project and screen captures showing debugger window and tool tip with the incorrect members/values being displayed.  Have also duplicated the issue on three separate machines (all with VS2019)

Comment: Also, FWIW, we have also seen the VS2019 debugger fall down with something like "static int thisIsPrivate=3;" as a private global in one file and "static int thisIsPrivate=7;" in another file.  When that happens, the debugger will only ever show the value one ONE of the private values that share names even though printf outputs the correct values.  This is a problem for me with several "object-esque" C modules that have similar private data.  Microsoft is looking into that bug, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is: Other than it being a bad coding practice, is there any reason why this code is wrong (strictly in a C compiler sense)?

I don't necessarily agree that the code exhibits poor practices.  It certainly is valid, as struct types do not need to be declared with tags in C.  Struct types without tags cannot be directly referenced outside the declaration in which they appear, but they serve just fine for declaring objects, and they are more commonly used in typedefs and larger structures.

For example, this approach is relatively common:

```
typedef struct {  // <-- no tag
    char *label;
    int   value;
} struct_one;

struct_one one[2] = {
    { "one", 1 },
    { "two", 2 }
};
```

After all, if you're not going to refer to the type via a tag anyway, then why introduce one into the tag namespace?

> I guess I'm interested in finding the standard reference to give
>   Microsoft if they try to tell me that this bug is my fault (though I
>   believe that either their compiler or debugger must be broken, since
>   the code should either not compile/link or should debug correctly,
>   right?)

Well, there's this piece of [C's formal grammar specification](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1p1):

struct-or-union-specifier:
struct-or-union identifier<sub>opt</sub> { struct-declaration-list }
struct-or-union identifier

The `opt` subscript indicates that the identifier (the tag in this case) is optional in `struct` and `union` definitions.  It is required for forward declarations of struct and union types, but that's not your case.  It follows from the rest of the formal grammar that any `struct-or-union-specifier` can be used to declare an object of that type or a type derived from it, such as an array type.

Moreover -- and I suspect that this is where the MS debugger falls down -- there is no limitation on the number of structure or union types declared without a tag.  Being without a tag is not the same thing as having an empty tag.

Ultimately, compilers (including Microsoft's) accept it, and I am fairly confident that you will find even the MSVC-compiled version to behave as expected, modulo program bugs.  That the debugger does not understand the variables' types correctly is definitely a bug in the debugger.

Do be aware, however, that Microsoft has historically shown little inclination to provide a conforming C compiler, theirs never having conformed to any version of the C language.  Most often, it is syntax and features that diverge from C++ that are poorly or un-supported by MS, as C++ has always been their focus.

Comment: The last paragraph is completely incorrect. MSVC has always been respected as one of the best C89/90 compilers on the market. Whatever non-conformance issues they had are typical (in quality and quantity) for the general state of C compilers. The internet fake from the beginning of 2000's about "C++ has always been their focus" has been overthrown and forgotten a long time ago. Modern MSVC supports C99 with only a few omissions (VLA, most notably).